# ITK installation and sample program

Tags: c++, visual-c++, image-processing, cmake, itk

I am new to ITK and I did the following step to install ITK and use it to programme in VS2010

1. Downloaded ITK 4.3.1 and build it with CMAKE
2. The build was successful and I had a lib->Debug folder containing the libs.
3. Added the bin folder path to environmental vairable path.

Following is my simple code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Core/Common/include/itkImage.h>

using namespace itk;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

the above code returns

```
Cannot open include file: 'itkConfigure.h'
```

I tried searching for that header but no luck. However in `C:\InsightToolkit-4.3.1\Modules\Core\Common\src` I found **itkConfigure.h.in** file. I am really clueless about how to go about this .in file. Any help is most welcome..

Comment: When having itk compiled, did not you forget to 'nmake install' it? If you keep it in build directory, that is a kind of errors you'll be getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to set up your project is to use CMake again.  Try creating a project with just a CMakeLists.txt and main.cpp.  The CMakeLists.txt should have something like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(ItkTest)

find_package(ITK REQUIRED)
include(${ITK_USE_FILE})

add_executable(MyTest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MyTest ITKCommon)
```

So say you create these 2 files in a dir called ItkProject, then from a *Visual Studio Command Prompt* just do:

```
cd <path to ItkProject>
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DITK_DIR="<path to build dir of ITK>"
```

The `<path to build dir of ITK>` is where you ran CMake from to configure the ITK project.  It will contain the ITK.sln file, but critically it should also contain a file called ITKConfig.cmake.  It is this file which is searched for in the cmake command `find_package(ITK REQUIRED)` - if CMake can't find it the configuring will fail.

Once that's been found, it sets a bunch of CMake variables which you can then use in your own CMakeLists.txt, including `ITK_USE_FILE`.

When you then invoke `include(${ITK_USE_FILE})`, this goes on to set up things like your includes paths, library search paths, and compiler flags.  The path `<path to ItkProject>/Core/Common/include` will be added to the includes dirs, so in your main.cpp, you just need to do:

```
#include <Core/Common/include/itkImage.h>
#include "itkImage.h"
```

Anyway, the end result after running CMake should be solution file `<path to ItkProject>\build\ItkTest.sln` which is set up ready to use ITK.

Answer (score 0):

I checked \ItkConfig.cmake and paths defined there should match physical paths, this is the case if ITK build has been untouched (directory wasn't renamed).

```
# The ITK source tree.
# For backward compatibility issues we still need to define this variable, although
# it is highly probable that it will cause more harm than being useful. 
# Use ITK_INCLUDE_DIRS instead, since ITK_SOURCE_DIR may point to non-existent directory
IF(NOT ITK_LEGACY_REMOVE)
  SET(ITK_SOURCE_DIR "C:/ITK320")
ENDIF(NOT ITK_LEGACY_REMOVE)

# The ITK include file directories.
SET(ITK_INCLUDE_DIRS "C:/ITK320-build;C:/ITK320/Code/Algorithms;C:/ITK320/Code/BasicFilters;C:/ITK320/Code/Common;C:/ITK320/Code/Numerics;C:/ITK320/Code/IO;C:/ITK320/Code/Numerics/FEM;C:/ITK320/Code/Numerics/NeuralNetworks;C:/ITK320/Code/SpatialObject;C:/ITK320/Utilities/MetaIO;C:/ITK320/Utilities/NrrdIO;C:/ITK320-build/Utilities/NrrdIO;C:/ITK320/Utilities/DICOMParser;C:/ITK320-build/Utilities/DICOMParser;C:/ITK320-build/Utilities/expat;C:/ITK320/Utilities/expat;C:/ITK320/Utilities/nifti/niftilib;C:/ITK320/Utilities/nifti/znzlib;C:/ITK320/Utilities/itkExtHdrs;C:/ITK320-build/Utilities;C:/ITK320/Utilities;C:/ITK320/Code/Numerics/Statistics;C:/ITK320/Utilities/vxl/v3p/netlib;C:/ITK320/Utilities/vxl/vcl;C:/ITK320/Utilities/vxl/core;C:/ITK320-build/Utilities/vxl/v3p/netlib;C:/ITK320-build/Utilities/vxl/vcl;C:/ITK320-build/Utilities/vxl/core;C:/ITK320-build/Utilities/gdcm;C:/ITK320/Utilities/gdcm/src")

# The ITK library directories.
SET(ITK_LIBRARY_DIRS "C:/ITK320-build/bin")
```